# Redirect dynamic site URL to its dynamic subdomain URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

noob here. how do i redirect:

**EDIT:**

```
http://domain.com/members/index.php/register/params?item=1&pname=productname&pid=1289465219
```

to

```
http://members.domain.com/index.php/register/params?item=1&pname=productname&pid=1289465219
```

with htaccess?

where "item", "pname" and "pid" vars are dynamic.

Comment: rewrites use regexes. "dynamic" just means "use wildcards here".

Comment: hello @MarcB. just as i mentioned, i'm new (not really yer familiar with htaccess/rewrites world). i'm just hoping that someone of you could give me a bit more direct answers as my time for this task is a bit limited :( --  thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)item=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pname=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)pid=
RewriteRule ^index\.php/register/params$ http://subdomain.domain.com/index.php/register/params [L,R]
```

Comment: Sorry, i updated my question. @Jon Lin will your solutions still apply?

Comment: slight changes from @Jon Lin but not working

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^teamaster\.com/members/$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)item=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cname=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)cemail=
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)ccountry=
RewriteRule ^index\.php/register/CUVow3$ http://members.teamaster.com/index.php/register/CUVow3 [L,R]` -- sorry bout my comment, backticks seems not working for codes